# Unknown MAC address under Personal Hotspot usage

Tags: macos, iphone, security, tethering, mac-address

Context: Personal hotspot connection from iPhone 12 used on my MacBook Air.

Problem: Under Settings - Mobile Data - Personal Hotspot (iPhone), I see 2 data usage components:

1.5 GB - MacBook, and,
20.2 KB - A very suspicious looking MAC address: 4a:f1:1b:3a:7d:86

Further information: I changed password multiple times, but the issue persists. Sometimes, I also see "Other devices"...

What is going on? Is my security in danger? Could this be related to MAC randomisation?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. On your Mac, can you run the following command in Terminal and post the output: `arp -l -a`? This command displays the IP-to-MAC address translation table. If the unknown MAC address is shown, the IP address could help identify the device (for example, with `sudo nmap -O <IP address>`. Note that `nmap` is not part of macOS, but can be installed with Homebrew).

Comment: Thank you Jaume. I will not have access to the hotspot for around a week, but will try as soon as I have the opportunity and update you. Now, if you look at the other answer below, would you agree that it could also be a possibility?

Comment: jksoegaard's answer is right that we're most probably dealing with a randomized MAC address: according to https://maclookup.app, the MAC address you see is a locally administered address as opposed to a "real" MAC address. My guess is that your Mac used a randomized MAC address while scanning for known Wi-Fi networks, and then, after connecting to it, if switched to its own MAC address (see https://support.apple.com/guide/security/wi-fi-privacy-secb9cb3140c/web), that would explain why only 20.2 KB were transferred.

Comment: Update -  I checked with Apple Support and they said this: "Okay so I just checked with a colleague it is with only iOS devices (iPhone, iPad and Watch), sorry about that. This feature hasnt been included on the Mac as of right now". So MacOS cannot randomise its MAC address while scanning for known Wi-Fi networks then?

Comment: Well, that's interesting, thanks for checking it out with Apple Support. I'd say what's going on is that some device (other than your Mac) scanned the Wi-Fi hotspot while using a randomized MAC address, and since only 20.2 KB were exchanged, I don't think your security is in danger.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that it might have scanned my hotspot, but did not connect to it? And thats why my security is not in danger

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Someone may have tried (unsuccessfully) to connect to your hotspot, and that's why we see some traffic logged for 4a:f1:1b:3a:7d:86.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you think that MAC address is "suspicious looking". It is not "suspicious looking" to me.

You can tell from the address itself that it is not a MAC address given to a network interface from factory by a hardware vendor - it is instead a software generated MAC address. This is very typical today - for example used in MAC randomisation, a scheme to protect the user privacy.

There's absolutely nothing here that indicates that your "security is in danger".

Comment: I appreciate the help! Thank you, but why would my data be used by this MAC address if I know that my MacBook is the only device connected to the personal hotspot being shared from my iPhone?

Comment: Because that MAC address IS the MacBook.

Comment: Interesting. But the MAC address is different from the Wi-Fi Address on my MacBook (System Report - Network - MAC address). What do you think?

Comment: Yes, exactly - it is software generated, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, so it is *randomized* (due to MAC address randomization being enabled on my MacBook), in other words?

Comment: It is also “randomized”, yes.

Comment: How do you tell from the MAC address that it's randomized?

Comment: You can't tell if a MAC address is truly randomized. I.e. someone might take a randomized MAC and duplicate 100 times, and those duplicates ofcourse wouldn't be "random". However, you can tell if a MAC address is assigned by hardware vendor, or it is a dynamic MAC address generated by software (which is typically a random address). The MAC address itself has this distinction encoded into it - similar to how it tells you whether it is a unicast or multicast address.